# Incorrect syntax near ', ' with multi-valued parameter in ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I can`t get the correct syntax when the query is declared as varchar.
My original query below worked as expected:

```
WHERE location in ('+@location+') AND costcentre in ('+@costcentre+') AND drug_name in ('+@drug_name+')
```

I get the syntax error on my current query if more than one value selected for any of the parameters:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT ....
WHERE location in ('+@location+') AND costcentre in ('+@costcentre+') AND drug_name in ('+@drug_name+')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server.  You should also show what the variables look like.

Comment: @eMRe usually when I do queries that involve parameters like that. I would use the syntax, `WHERE location in (@location)`. It is already an array of strings essentially so you shouldn't need to specify the single quotes around the parameter

Comment: What `@location` hold? strings? number?

Comment: @Sami it is string

Comment: @arahman it did not work. It doesnot recognize the parameter if i do: WHERE location in (@location)

Comment: @eMRe Apologies I did not see that it is being used as a varchar query parameter type.

Comment: @eMRe Just wondering, why do you need the query to be as a parameter in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think here, quotes will break the string. If I understood correct, this will work(changed ['] -> [''] and concatenated the variable with value).

```
    SET @query = 'SELECT ....
WHERE location in (''' + @location + ''') AND costcentre in (''' + @costcentre + ''') AND drug_name in (''' + @drug_name + ''')
```

Also try to print @query if the above not works.

Comment: Not sure about the @location variable

Comment: I get the same error if i select more than i value. How can I print and view the query on the visual studio?

Comment: I hope the code should work as it will create the similar query statement to the one that worked

Comment: what is the size of @query variable? if it is small, it will truncate the query. Also, what it returns with print?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to Join the parameter selections? I'm assuming @location is a parameter, so something like:

```
Join(Parameters!location.Value, ",")
```

This link may also be of some help:
https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/2/25/displaying-single-multi-valued-report-parameter-selections-i.html